# Excel VBA Codes Not Working in Newer Version

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have written some codes in Excel 2010 and gave them to a colleague who has Excel 2013.  However, they just are not working properly in the newer version of Excel.  For example, when you are pressing a button on a user-form, it should open up the tab corresponding to a chosen account, but on his machine, every button is pointing to the same tab.  I already checked his VBA reference libraries, and that does not seem to be the issue.  What can be the difference between various versions of Excel?  I am just surprised that my colleague's newer version is not running on codes written in an older version?

**Sample Codes**

```
Sub GotoAccount()

Dim wksMaster as Workbook
Dim SheetName as String
Set wksMaster = Workbooks("2019 Account Log.xlsm")
SheetName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
With Sheets(SheetName)
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
End With

End Sub
```

This sub is supposed to bring out the tab associated with a particular account in the log.  The `Application.Caller` object is the button, and the account number is hiding behind it.  Thus, the assignment statement for `SheetName` is recording the account number, and it will be used to pull up the tab whose name is the account number.  As it turned out, there was a slight mistake; the `Sheets` collection is not connected to `wkbMaster`.  However, rather than crashing completely, Excel is pulling the tab for another account recorded in the log.  This is why I am suspecting that Excel 2013 is processing some of the codes differently.

Comment: It is unlikely that the version of Excel is making any difference. Is your code using [Select and Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513) by any chance?

Comment: Better share the code with us, will help to test it to fix the issue !

Comment: I avoided `activesheets` etc as much as I could.  The exception is when it is referencing a tab the user manually clicked on.  Plus, I am switching to late binding.  Let me see if I can put up the codes; it's long .... Thanks!